# How to implement sleep function for blocking code in javascript

Tags: javascript, typescript

I want to implement a sleep function that functions like the following like this:

```js
console.log(123)
slepp(2000)
console.log(456)
```

run it:

```js
123
waiting two seconds...
456
```

I want to get a solution about sleep function implements

Comment: Please visit [help], take [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output, preferably in a [Stacksnippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)

Answer (score 2):

Did this myself just the other day on a project.

```
function sleep(delay) {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      resolve();
    }, delay);
  });
}
```

You can use by: `await sleep(2000)` for a 2 second delay.

Comment: if the add condition is not used await syntax, Is there another solution? This is an interview question I came across.

Answer (score 2):

Here's the function that I add to almost every project I have:

```
/**
 * Async function to sleep for `ms` amound of milliseconds.
 * @param ms - time to sleep in milliseconds
 * @returns `Promise<void>` after the sleep time has passed.
 */
export async function sleep(ms: number): Promise<void> {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      resolve();
    }, ms);
  });
}
```

Edit: Looks like @John Detlefs beat me to it by 2 minutes, didn't notice it while the question was already open :)

Comment: Thank you for answer my question.But if the add condition is not used await syntax, Is there another solution? This is an interview question I came across.

Comment: @vikoala as far as I am aware, it's not possible without async/await. Even if you use other libraries like lodash or RxJS to simulate sleeping with callback functions, they will eventually use Promises.